# Dynamics NAV (a replicated Database) Does Not Open?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-nav, transactional-replication

Experts

I was able to replicate an NAV test Database to another server instances. I used Transaction Replication. This was successful, whenever a transaction was completed in the original database, the results could be seen in the replicated SQL Database (e.g. posting sales orders). However, when I connected the replicated Database to an NAV instance and started running NAV, the program returned a fatal Error.

Later, I took backup of the replicated database and restored it to a new database. The same issue came up. I even cleared up the Access Control table, User, and the session list.

Your support is appreciated.

Thanks.

**Fatal Error**

[image]

Comment: What Event Viewer says? There should be extended description of the error.

Comment: I was about to say the same as Mak Sim was said. Check the Event Log. In most of the cases behind every meaningless NAV Error message there is an Error Message in the Event Log which actually makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks Guys!! I checked the event log.... and I get this error it seems I get SIFT Error.
  **FTPL-SNAPSHOT.dbo.FLINTEC$Prod_ Order Routing Line$VSIFT$0' is invalid.**

Comment: I think the Views are haven't been replicated from the other database. The VSIFT Views are belongs to the FlowFields.

Comment: SFIT tables have been replicated!! I checked the indexes in the replicated database. However, some sources suggest to not to replicate the indexes...